# Set height of SVG to line-height?

Tags: css, svg

I want to include my SVG image as an icon next to the headline:

```
<h1 ><img src="icon-sell.svg" class="icon"> Verkaufen</h1>
```

The font-size of `h1` is `36px` and the `line-heigt` is `1.1`.

I used the inspector tool to find that the computed height of the font is `42.3px`. If I set the height of the `svg` to  `42.px`, then they do not match:

[image]

I also think its a bit dirty to use the inspector tool, because for different zooming level the height changed a little bit and I wanted to use svg to make sure it fits on every screen properly.

Any advice how the svg image can automatically get the height of the font and also match up with it?

Here is a snippet:

```css
.icon{
  height: 43.75px;
}

h1{
  font-size:36px;
  line-height:1;
}
```

```html
<h1>
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f7/Bananas.svg" class="icon">
Headline
</h1>
```

Comment: You can use the " img { display: inline-block; vertical-align:middle; } "

Comment: @Md.AbuSayed this does not quite work, the text and the image do not match, see https://i.stack.imgur.com/tP65w.png - also, I would prefere a solution where I do not need to set the height of the svg manually.

Comment: this code work when you give the large image with text then the made text middle and when image small size then the middle image related text.

Comment: you can also see this link : https://jsfiddle.net/h6s9mwuo/

Comment: @Md.AbuSayed in your related jsfiddle the text is slightly above the image.

Comment: You can also wrap the text with an inline element here h1 span,
h1 img {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle
}  the link: https://jsfiddle.net/6xg5ho8s/

Comment: @Md.AbuSayed yes that works. I found another solution that does not require the additional span: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55118108/2311074

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189868/discussion-between-md-abu-sayed-and-adam).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would consider the svg as a background-image to be sure it will match the height without setting any height:

```css
h1 {
  line-height: 1;
  padding-left: 1.8em;
  background-size: auto 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<h1 style="background-image:url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f7/Bananas.svg)">
  Headline
</h1>

<h1 style="font-size:50px;background-image:url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f7/Bananas.svg)">
  Headline
</h1>
<h1 style="font-size:10px;background-image:url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f7/Bananas.svg)">
  Headline
</h1>
```

Comment: Uh this is great! But this works only for images that have a width less then 1.8em, right?

Comment: @Adam it can work with any image, simply adjust the padding value depending on the ratio of your image ... make it bigger or smaller to fit your SVG and to control the distance with text

Comment: Oh, my bad. I thought you wanted to align the top-most pixel of the text with the top-most pixel of the banana

Comment: Is this the math that you did: The banana has a width of 559px and height of 373px. So width is 1.5 times the height. Thus if line height is 1, i.e. its the same height as font-site, we need to a width of 1.5em. And to add a little space to the banana, you added 0.3em, so left padding is 1.8em?

Comment: @Adam probably .. it was 4 years ago so I forgot :)

Answer (score 2):

This CSS works using an inline SVG. Using an SVG as a background image prevents changing the color with the text as well. The below matches the SVG to the height and color of the text.

```css
.svg {
    fill: currentColor;
    line-height: 1;
    height: 1em;
    width: 1em; 
}
```

```html
<h1><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="svg" viewBox="0 0 400 400"><path class="svg-path" d="M13 2.5a1.5 1.5 0 0 1 3 0v11a1.5 1.5 0 0 1-3 0v-11zm-1 .724c-2.067.95-4.539 1.481-7 1.656v6.237a25.222 25.222 0 0 1 1.088.085c2.053.204 4.038.668 5.912 1.56V3.224zm-8 7.841V4.934c-.68.027-1.399.043-2.008.053A2.02 2.02 0 0 0 0 7v2c0 1.106.896 1.996 1.994 2.009a68.14 68.14 0 0 1 .496.008 64 64 0 0 1 1.51.048zm1.39 1.081c.285.021.569.047.85.078l.253 1.69a1 1 0 0 1-.983 1.187h-.548a1 1 0 0 1-.916-.599l-1.314-2.48a65.81 65.81 0 0 1 1.692.064c.327.017.65.037.966.06z"/></svg> Test</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

The following matches the image and the text next to each other, however I still have to set a fixed height for the svg image.

```css
  
.icon{
  height: 36px;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
}

h1{
  font-size:36px;
  line-height:1.1;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

```html
  
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f7/Bananas.svg" class="icon">
<h1>
Headline
</h1>
```

Comment: you want to center or to have the same height? because this code is not producing the same height

Comment: @TemaniAfif I am looking for a solution where the height are the same and are automatically computed.

Answer (score -1):

Go through it, it will work.

```css
h2{display:flex;align-item:center;}
```

Comment: this does not quite work, the text and the image do not match, see i.stack.imgur.com/tP65w.png - also, I would prefere a solution where I do not need to set the height of the svg manually.

Comment: I have update my answer, check again, it will work for you @Adam

Comment: Thank you for your help. However, the text is still slightly above the image. https://jsfiddle.net/cr0dz2m4/