# How do I set the height of an SVG to the height of its enclosing container?

Tags: css, svg, height, css-grid

Apparently, setting the `svg`'s `height` to `100%` doesn't always work.

Consider the following snippet:

```js
function createBar(color) {
 const svg = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg')
  
  const rect = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'rect')
  svg.appendChild(rect)
  rect.setAttribute('height', '100%')
  rect.setAttribute('width', '100%')
  rect.setAttribute('fill', color)
  
  return svg
}

document.getElementById('health').appendChild(createBar('crimson'))
document.getElementById('stamina').appendChild(createBar('orange'))
document.getElementById('shield').appendChild(createBar('teal'))
```

```css
ul {
  display: grid;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  grid-template-columns: max-content 1fr;
}

li {
  display: contents;
}

svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li id="health"><span>Health: </span></li>
<li id="stamina"><span>Stamina: </span></li>
<li id="shield"><span>Shield: </span></li>
</ul>
```

My intention was to set these 3 `svg`s to match the height of the lines. I thought I'd be clever with my `height: 100%` solution: If I made certain that `100%` referred to the height of the line, setting the `svg` to `height: 100%` would give me what I wanted.

Sadly, as you can see above, this wont work. The svgs are enormous.

I am surprised because if I remove the svgs and replace them with `spans` this suddenly starts working exactly as expected:

```css
ul {
  display: grid;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  grid-template-columns: max-content 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: max-content;
}

li {
  display: contents;
}

span:last-child {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li><span>Health: </span><span style="background-color: crimson;"></span></li>
<li><span>Stamina: </span><span style="background-color: orange;"></span></li>
<li><span>Shield: </span><span style="background-color: teal;"></span></li>
</ul>
```

Why do `svg`s not obey `height: 100%`, even though `span`s do obey this? How can I make the `svg`s height match the height of the enclosing container anyway? That is, while making certain the enclosing container's height matches the height of the line - I don't want to set the height of the text ('Stamina', 'Shield', 'Health') explicitely to eg `10px`.

### Appendix: Why I want it and research I've done

- I want the `svg` height to match the height of the line that says `Shield`, `Health`, `Stamina`;
- [This question discusses this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15940338/is-there-a-way-via-css-to-set-the-image-height-to-the-line-height), but:

  - Its first answer suggests setting the image's height to `1em` but despite the green tick and upvotes this is simply wrong, even though it works with `svg`s. Proof below.
  - Its second answer suggests explicitely setting the line height, which I'd like to avoid. Reason: Throughout the site I'm using `font-size`s like `smaller`.
- [Another question that discusses it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55117226/set-height-of-svg-to-line-height). It has 3 answers:

  - First suggests setting the `svg` as abackground image - I don't want it since I want to generate the `svg` via JS;
  - Second once again suggest explicitly setting the line height
  - Third answer wants to use flexbox but I want to use grid for the reason that I want the division into 2 columns.

Proof that setting to `1em` won't work:

```js
function createBar(color) {
 const svg = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg')
  
  const rect = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'rect')
  svg.appendChild(rect)
  rect.setAttribute('height', '100%')
  rect.setAttribute('width', '100%')
  rect.setAttribute('fill', color)
  
  return svg
}

document.getElementById('health').appendChild(createBar('crimson'))
document.getElementById('stamina').appendChild(createBar('orange'))
document.getElementById('shield').appendChild(createBar('teal'))
```

```css
ul {
  display: grid;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  grid-template-columns: max-content 1fr;
}

li {
  display: contents;
}

svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1em;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li id="health"><span>Health: </span></li>
<li id="stamina"><span>Stamina: </span></li>
<li id="shield"><span>Shield: </span></li>
</ul>
```

As you can see there are white gaps between the bars.

Comment: which browser? the first snippet works well on Chrome

Comment: @TemaniAfif Does it? I'm surprised. I'm on Firefox.

Comment: yes only firefox is failling .. as a side note, the height in the last snippet need to be 1.2em to have the full height because the line-height is by default set to 1.2

Comment: @TemaniAfif 1.2? Didnt know this. Isnt it OS / browser / user's theme / user's font / etc dependant?

Comment: here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height#Values .. it's roughly the default value which is `normal` ... of course note the *roughly*, so not robust as solution but may work

Comment: and since I have provided this solution : *First suggests setting the svg as abackground image - I don't want it since I want to generate the svg via JS;* --> you can easily embed the SVG generate using JS inside the inline declaration of background image

Comment: @TemaniAfif *you can easily embed the SVG generate using JS inside the inline declaration of background image* Wow, how could I have not though about this. Thank you .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it works fine using span, consider the SVG inside the span element. Note the use of `height:0;min-height:100%` to avoid creating a cycle with `height:100%`. So we set the height to 0 (it won't affect the height of the parents) then we force it to 100% using min-height (we already have the height of the parent element)

```js
function createBar(color) {
 const svg = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg')
  
  const rect = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'rect')
  svg.appendChild(rect)
  rect.setAttribute('height', '100%')
  rect.setAttribute('width', '100%')
  rect.setAttribute('fill', color)
  
  return svg
}

document.querySelector('#health span:last-child').appendChild(createBar('crimson'))
document.querySelector('#stamina span:last-child').appendChild(createBar('orange'))
document.querySelector('#shield span:last-child').appendChild(createBar('teal'))
```

```css
ul {
  display: grid;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  grid-template-columns: max-content 1fr;
}

li {
  display: contents;
}


span:last-child{
  display:block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
svg {
  display:block;
  height:0;
  min-height:100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li id="health"><span>Health: </span><span></span></li>
<li id="stamina"><span>Stamina: </span><span></span></li>
<li id="shield"><span>Shield: </span><span></span></li>
</ul>
```

In your code you are facing an issue related to percentage height where the reference isn't explicetely defined so it's failling to auto. Note that it's working fine with Chrome which is able to identify the reference to be the height of the text content.